# Stacking up multiple shapely polygons to form a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I have a bunch of Shapely polygons that overlap. Each shape represents one particular observation of the object in the wild. I want to build up some sort of a cumulative observation (heatmap?) by combining the polygons together. Not just the union: I want to combine them in such a way that I can threshold it together and form a better estimate of where the object actually is. What is the best to "rasterize" the shapely polygon?

Comment: You mean like a density image? Each pixel would have a count for the number of occurrences?

Comment: Yeah, kinda like this. There is no pixel yet: but I guess I can rasterize it.

Comment: You can also intersect all of the patches and color map the number of intersections but this sounds like a lot of trouble just to get an svg alike image.  If you want to scale to different sizes, though, you might need to consider it. But personally,...yeah, I would go with a raster.

Comment: It is not clear to me what do you want exactly, and what do you need it for. Do you want just a colored image? Do you want a function that can tell you, for each point, how many polygons intersect the points? Do you want a set of disjoint polygons, any representing a different "visit density"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one could perhaps proceed by adding one polygon at a time, keep a list of disjoint shapes and remember for each of them how many polygons contributed:

```
import copy
from itertools import groupby
from random import randint, seed
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, box
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

polygons = [
    Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (0, 0)]),
    Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)]),
    Polygon([(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1)])
]

def check_shape(s):
    return (s.geom_type in ['Polygon', 'MultiPolygon'] and not s.is_empty)

shapes = []
for p in polygons:

    polygon = copy.deepcopy(p)
    new_shapes = []
    for shape_cnt, shape in shapes:

        new_shapes.extend([
            (shape_cnt, shape.difference(polygon)),
            (shape_cnt+1, shape.intersection(polygon))
        ])

        polygon = polygon.difference(shape)
    new_shapes.append((1, polygon))

    shapes = list(filter(lambda s: check_shape(s[1]), new_shapes))

for p in polygons:
    print(p)

for cnt, g in groupby(sorted(shapes, key = lambda s: s[0]), key = lambda s: s[0]):
    print(cnt, cascaded_union(list(map(lambda s: s[1], g))))
```

This then produces:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))
POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
POLYGON ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((2 1, 2 0, 1 0, 1 1, 2 1)), ((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1)))
2 MULTIPOLYGON (((1 0, 0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0)), ((1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 2)))
```